# Hello. Every Time I want to add a new book to my booklist, it does not show me thw information in the table

Tags: javascript

here is my HTML code: it gets the information of the new book stores it in the local storage and also shows it in the table. The problem however is that every time I add a new book, it does not show the information in the table despite storing it in the local storage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <title>My BookList App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container mt-4">
      <h1 class="display-4 text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-book-open text-warning"></i> SabzLearn Js<span
          class="text-warning"
        >
          Book</span
        >List
      </h1>
      <form id="book-form" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="author">Author</label>
          <input type="text" id="author" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="year">Year</label>
          <input type="text" id="year" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Add Book"
          class="btn btn-warning btn-block"
        />
      </form>
      <table class="table table-striped mt-5 text-center">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Year</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="book-list">
          <tr>
            <th>اثر مرکب</th>
            <th>علی محمدی</th>
            <th>2010</th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this one is my JavaScript code. The code seems correct but....

```
let $ = document;
let titleElem = $.querySelector('#title');
let authorElem = $.querySelector('#author');
let yearElem = $.querySelector('#year');
let addBookButton = $.querySelector('.btn');
let bookListShowcase = $.getElementById('book-list');
let bookListArray = [];

addBookButton.addEventListener('click', function bookHandler() {
  let bookName = titleElem.value;
  let authorName = authorElem.value;
  let publishYear = yearElem.value;
  let newBookInfo = { name: bookName, author: authorName, year: publishYear };
  bookListArray.push(newBookInfo);

  // Clear input fields after adding a book
  titleElem.value = '';
  authorElem.value = '';
  yearElem.value = '';

  // Create table row and cells for the new book
  let newTableRow = $.createElement('tr');
  let tdName = $.createElement('td');
  tdName.textContent = bookName;
  let tdAuthor = $.createElement('td');
  tdAuthor.textContent = authorName;
  let tdYear = $.createElement('td');
  tdYear.textContent = publishYear;

  // Append cells to the row and row to the table
  newTableRow.appendChild(tdName);
  newTableRow.appendChild(tdAuthor);
  newTableRow.appendChild(tdYear);
  bookListShowcase.appendChild(newTableRow);

  localStorage.setItem('bookListArray', JSON.stringify(bookListArray));
});

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  let storedBookList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookListArray'));
  if (storedBookList) {
    bookListArray = storedBookList;
    bookListArray.forEach(bookHandler);
  }
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.